# run spotify in background on windows 8.1 with screen off (tablet)

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, tablet

I run windows 8.1 on Linx7 tablet, installed Spotify on it and it runs great. However when the screen goes dark the music stops. Can it be changed so spotify runs in background with audio output on?